# Matlab formula optimization without for loops

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, vectorization, hough-transform

I am trying to implement Hough transform algorithm. Algorithm works, but it's slow.
Currently i calculate rho, by this equation in two for loops:

> for i = 1 : length(x)
>
> ```
> j=1;
> for theta = -pi/2:nBinsTheta:pi/2-nBinsTheta
>
>   ro =round(x(i).*cos(theta) + y(i).*sin(theta));
>
>   ....
>  j = j + 1;
>  end
> ```
>
> end

How can i simplify this, to work without for loops?
I need to calculate ro without loops, but how can i do this, to cover all possible theta's?

---

EDIT: Now i need to know how to add 1, to designated cell's in accumulator matrix given x and y coordinate vector. For example let's say that i have vectors like:

> x: [1 2 1 3]
>   y: [1 3 1 4]

I'd like to solve this problem without loops. I know that i need to convert to linear indices using **sub2ind**, but the problem is that there'll be a lot of same linear indices for example that i gave, there will be **2x1 (1,1 coordinate is repeated twice)**. If you try to add 1 like so:

> A([1 1]) = A([1 1]) + 1;

it'll add 1 only once, that's my problem.

Comment: What's the use of `j` in there?

Comment: j is meant to acces proper value in accumulator array for theta's for voting

Comment: Could you format the EDIT section? It's hard to read that as it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `x` and `y` to be row vectors, you can use the following code to pre-calculate all `ro` values in a 2D matrix which hopefully should speed things up for you inside the nested loops for the rest of the work you might be doing involving the `ro` values -

```
theta_vec = [-pi/2:nBinsTheta:pi/2-nBinsTheta].'; %//'
ro_vals = round( cos(theta_vec)*x + sin(theta_vec)*y );
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea, now i have a new problem. I need to add 1 to a accumulator array for each theta-rho value. The problem is that it happens that i need to add 1 multiple times to the same cell in accumulator matrix and matlab has problem with code like for example: A([1 1 1]) = A([ 1 1 1]) + 1, it will add 1 only once. My problem is when i say A(rho(:), theta(:)) = A(rho(:), theta(:)) + 1; there is a lot of duplicate rhos's and theta's and therefore won't properly add 1 multiple times. How can i do that in different manner? Theta and rho are discretized before to proper interval...

Comment: @EWER115 It's hard to read the codes through the comments. Could you edit the question with those additional details and codes?

Answer (score 0):

```
assert(all(size(x) == size(y)), 'dimension mismatch: x, y')

theta = (-pi/2:nBinsTheta:pi/2-nBinsTheta)';

assert(all(size(theta) == size(y)), 'dimension mismatch: theta, y')

rho = x.*cos(theta) + y.*sin(theta);

rho_rounded = round(rho);
```

do you really need `j`?

PS: the previous answer might not work because of matrix multiplication operator `*` instead of elementwise `.*`

Comment: Well in my solution (the other one), I am using matrix multiplication involving two vectors resulting in a 2D matrix (as stated in it). That is, it's like `Nx1` multiplied by `1xM` and that is not elementwise multiplication, it's a matrix multiplication, resulting in the same values as with `ro` inside those nested loops. So, that should work :)